# Automatically Add CloudWatch LogGroup to another LogGroup?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda

I have a `Logger` Lambda function that listens on a specific LogGroup and process specific log details.

I would like to attach the newly created LogGroups of other lambdas to that specific LogGroup, so it will process them as well - but since these other lambdas are created automatically, I need to do this automatically. Can I do it? How?

Answer (score 3):

So there's no way to directly replicate the logs stored in a CloudWatch log group to another log group. You could do this by creating a [subscription filter with a Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) to push the logs from each log group to the common one, but this would increase the costs for CloudWatch.

What I would suggest is either of the following:

- Create a subscription filter for each of the log groups used by your Lambda functions to the common Lambda function so that it is triggered when logs are pushed to any of the log groups. This event can be set up after creating each function. Note, you would have to update the function policy of the common Lambda to allow it to be invoked from each log group (or just set up a wildcard).
- Push all the logs for all of the functions to a single log group. This would take the least effort, but you would have to figure out how to effectively separate the logs per function (if that is required for your use case).

Comment: just a rant: it's really shame that AWS CWL does not allow to create one LogGroup as a combination or SubscriptionFilter from another LogGroup